# Serialize dictionary to json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, restsharp

I Have any method:

```
IExternalResponse<ReserveResponse> ReserveFreePlacement(IDictionary<int,int> ticketsInfo) {
    var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
    request.AddJsonBody(
        new
        {
            command = "RESERVATION",
            categoryQuantityMap = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticketsInfo),
        });
    return GetResult<ReserveResponse>(request, RestClient, "Reservation"); }
```

request is `RestSharp.RestRequest`, ticketsInfo is a dictionary with a values:

```
Key:12041, Value:1
Key:12040, Value:2
```

After command "AddJsonBody" i have in request.Parameters 1 parameter

```
application/json={
  "command": "RESERVATION",
  "categoryQuantityMap": "{\"12041\":1,\"12040\":1}",
  "versionCode": "1.0"
}
```

but i need

```
application/json={
  "command": "RESERVATION",
  "categoryQuantityMap": {
    "12041":1,
    "12040":2
    },
  "versionCode": "1.0"
}
```

How do i get the right one?

Comment: What type does your `categoryQuantityMap`have? If it is a string then it will be escaped. Can you type your `categoryQuantityMap`to the actual data?

Comment: `categoryQuantityMap = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticketsInfo),` is just going to convert the dictionary to a JSON string. Did you try `categoryQuantityMap = ticketsInfo`?

Comment: I can change type ticketsInfo to get the desired result

Comment: When i don't use SerializeObject than i have tuples with "key" and "value" keywords. I know, that  SerializeObject give me string value, and it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem in implementing method serialization of AddJsonBody. When i by handle serialize object then by handle add body request - everything is correct:

```
IExternalResponse<ReserveResponse> ReserveFreePlacement(IDictionary<int,int> ticketsInfo) 
{
    var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new
    {
        command = "RESERVATION",
        categoryQuantityMap = ticketsInfo,
        versionCode = "1.0"
    });
    var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    return GetResult<ReserveResponse>(request, RestClient, "Reservation");
}
```